# Gradle can't find tests anymore after Spring Boot upgrade to 2.3.2

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

We recently upgraded our Kotlin Spring Boot project so Spring Boot 2.3.2 and since then it seems that gradle can no longer pick up any tests.

We were using the gradle wrapper 5.6.2 and upgraded to 6.3 even though [the documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes) stated that 5.6.x should work as well. The Gradle upgrade did not help and gradle still can not pick up any tests, when I downgrade to 2.2.3 it works fine. We are using Kotest, Junit5 and an embedded mongodb for our tests.

```
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.3.50"
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion

    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.3.2.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"

    id("jacoco")
}

dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:6.1")
        dependency("com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0")

        val kotlintestVersion = "3.4.2"
        dependency("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5:$kotlintestVersion")
        dependency("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-extensions-spring:$kotlintestVersion")
        dependency("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-assertions:$kotlintestVersion")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }

    testImplementation("org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")

    testImplementation("com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin")

    testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit5")
    testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-extensions-spring")
    testImplementation("io.kotlintest:kotlintest-assertions")
}

val jacocoTask = tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
    reports {
        xml.isEnabled = true
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    doFirst {
        environment("SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT", "${project.mongo.port}")
    }
    this.extra.set("runWithMongoDb", true)
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy(jacocoTask)
}

mongo {
    setPort("RANDOM")
}
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-XXLanguage:+InlineClasses")
}
```

Any hint on what I might be doing wrong?

One of our very simple tests:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
class HardwareServiceApplicationSpec : FunSpec() {

    override fun listeners(): List<TestListener> {
        return listOf(SpringListener)
    }

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var rmqMessageReceiver: RmqMessageReceiver

    init {
        test("the messageReceiver bean is created on application startup") {
            assertThat(rmqMessageReceiver).isNotNull()
        }
    }
}
```

The log output of the test also doesn't help me a lot:

```
> Task :test
file or directory 'C:\Users\Pia Gerhofer\Projects\hw-service-v2\build\classes\java\test', not found
Excluding []
Caching disabled for task ':test' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':test' is not up-to-date because:
  Task.upToDateWhen is false.
Extracting Mongo binaries...
Starting Mongod 4.0.2 on port 55319...
start de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfigBuilder$ImmutableMongodConfig@7f4e7fe1
Mongod started.

file or directory 'C:\Users\Pia Gerhofer\Projects\hw-service-v2\build\classes\java\test', not found
Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 3'. Working directory: C:\Users\Pia Gerhofer\Projects\hw-service-v2 Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5\bin\java.exe -Dorg.gradle.native=false -javaagent:build/tmp/expandedArchives/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5.jar_6a2df60c47de373ea127d14406367999/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/test.exec,append=true,inclnolocationclasses=false,dumponexit=true,output=file,jmx=false @C:\Users\Pia Gerhofer\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle-worker-classpath2455123809837509056txt -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=AT -Duser.language=de -Duser.variant -ea worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 3'
Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 3'

Gradle Test Executor 3 started executing tests.

> Task :test

~~~ Project Configuration ~~~


Gradle Test Executor 3 STANDARD_OUT
    ~~~ Project Configuration ~~~
-> Parallelism: 1 thread

    -> Parallelism: 1 thread
-> Test order: LexicographicSpecExecutionOrder

    -> Test order: LexicographicSpecExecutionOrder
-> Soft assertations: False

    -> Soft assertations: False
-> Write spec failure file: False

    -> Write spec failure file: False
-> Fail on ignored tests: False

    -> Fail on ignored tests: False
-> Extensions

    -> Extensions
  - io.kotlintest.extensions.SystemPropertyTagExtension

      - io.kotlintest.extensions.SystemPropertyTagExtension
  - io.kotlintest.extensions.RuntimeTagExtension

      - io.kotlintest.extensions.RuntimeTagExtension


Gradle Test Executor 3 finished executing tests.

> Task :test FAILED
```

So I see no exception or any other problem in the logs even though I get the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [com.tractive.hwservice.HardwareServiceApplicationSpec](filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

Any help is appreciated, I already tried various gradle versions, no combination worked so far. A colleague told me I might have to use a different test runner but I can't find anything concerning that in the upgrade guide/documentation.

Interestingly enough I upgraded another of our services to the latest spring boot version, which uses gradle wrapper 6.4 and the tests work as expected there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work with any of the Gradle versions, tried it with (5.6.x, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5 and 6.6).

The thing we were missing is updating the kotlin `plugin.spring` version. After we updated that to `1.3.72` instead of `1.3.50` everything was working as expected.